# Multi-targeting .NET framework wreaks Intellisense/Resharper havok

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, resharper, intellisense

I am working on understanding [this](https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com) project and noticed that the creator tried to make the project work for many build targets (Silverlight, WPF, Win8.1).

He's done this through the use of 4 projects: a base project for all his controls and code, and three other project (one for each target type).

The SL/WPF/Win8.1 projects all simply contain linked references to the base project.

Then, in his base project he extensively uses code like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
namespace De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;

#if NETFX_CORE
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.Foundation;
    using Windows.UI;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;
    using Windows.UI.Core;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

#else
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows;
#endif

    public class ChartArea : ContentControl
    {
        static ChartArea()
        {
#if NETFX_CORE

#elif SILVERLIGHT

#else
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ChartArea), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ChartArea)));
#endif
}
```

This imports the correct references depending on what platform is running.

However, the side-effect is that Resharper totally freaks out, and Intellisense can't find things like `ContentControl`. Yet, it all builds fine.

Is this the preferred way of designing solutions that target multiple platforms? It's making extending the code very difficult because I can't tell what's a legitimate error and what's just an issue with parsing the directives.

Comment: What version of ReSharper are you using? I have had issues with certain directives in ReSharper 7 that seemed to be fixed in ReSharper 8 (I am currently stuck on 7). If it's not the latest version of ReSharper, you could install the latest as a trial and see if they fixed the issue.

Comment: I can't recall how well ReSharper handled linked files, but universal app projects and especially referenced C++ based WinRT components break it enough that I just disabled R# today for the first time in a really long while to get rid of all the noise. As to what's the preferred way to handle multi targeting - this seems to be the pattern that everyone follows. I guess we should just push jetBrains to focus more on fixing this problem since multi targeting is becoming more of a norm these days.

Comment: @TyCobb: I am running R# 8.2, the latest.
To FilipSkakun: Unfortunately (or fortunately) it runs fine with R# disabled.